# Query db with supplied where condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my search form I let the user specify which columns and what word to search for in that specific column.

What I get is a key-value mapping where `key = column` and `value = search words`. I loop through these keys and values and create a string (*searchPhrase*) that I want to use in my query. Something like:

```
var query =
db.Persons.
Where(searchPhrase);
```

But I don't know how to use my *searchPhrase* as a where condition?

Here's how I loop through my form collection

```
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
{
    List<string> conditions = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["columnName" + i]))
        {
            string s = String.Empty;
            s += collection["Attributes" + i].ToString();
            s += " = '";
            s += collection["searchWord" + i].ToString();
            s += "'";
            conditions.Add(s);
         }
    }
    searchPhrase = string.Join(" AND ", conditions.ToArray());
}
```

I then want to use the searchPhrase in the above query which might look like
`surname LIKE 'adam' AND surname LIKE 'bob'`

This is the only way I can think of since I'm letting the user specify the columns.

**EDIT**
Here's the search form:  *(Btw, this is an admin feature so I'm not too worried about sql injection attacks)*
[image]

Comment: Is that a LINQ query? If it is a SQL Query are just making your system susceptible to SQL Injection attacks by concatenating strings like that.

Comment: Ugh. Can't you provide a screenshot of the UI, and we'll suggest a better option. This is crazy stuff.

Comment: I'd like it to be a LINQ query, but I'm not sure as how to let the user specify the columns and still use LINQ. It's not necessary to concatenate strings but it's the only way I could think of, or do you know another way?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: Isn't the query above dynamic linq?

Comment: Did you had a look at the link. You try to execute a dynamic Linq query and the dynamic Linq library (linked) allows you to do that.

Comment: I don't know how to add the system.linq.dynamic? Is it included in the system.linq, cause I have that. Do I have to add the dynamic bit separately?

Comment: download the c# sample, import the `DynamicLibrary.cs` file into your project and you are done. Then add `using System.Linq.Dynamic` (its in the cs defined) and use the extension methods that are available now.

Comment: Using dynamic it still didn't work. Shouldn't this query work? `db.Persons.Where("surname LIKE 'bob' AND lastname LIKE 'stone'");`

Comment: Should work if `Person` has these properties.

Comment: When I run this query `db.Persons.Where("surname = bob")` it say *No property or field 'bob' exists in type 'Person'*. Seems like it thinks bob is the column and not surname?

Comment: You didn't quote your value, so it may be a comparison of two properties.